# Kill sibling process

Tags: bash

I would like to have a script which would :

- trigger a `make 2&>1 | less -R`
- listen for every change in the folder (using `inotifywait -R`)

When the folder is modified, the script would have to kill the `less` process and restart.

I'm not sure about the right way to do this (allow to the two branches of the script to run in parallel + allow the watching job to know the pid of the `less` job, since the latter have to be in foreground).

Comment: What is the overall goal of this?  Do you want to be able to monitor the make and every time it updates refresh the view?

Comment: Yes. I want to have two terminals side by side, and recompile every time I save a file (to see the new compilation errors).

Comment: Would redirecting the output to a file instead of piping to less then using a tail -f fileName in the other terminal be acceptable?  It keeps an open stream to the file and show updates as they occur without need to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to trigger an automatic recompile each time something is changed, then you could try the following:

```
while inotifywait -qqr /dir/to/watch; do
   make | less
done
```

I realize that this solution does not kill the less command each time a recompile is issued

A slight variation of the above is to put less after done:

```
while inotifywait -qqr /dir/to/watch; do
   make
done | less
```

This version will immediately trigger a recompile (after the first make has finished), but it will require that you page through all of the output from less (and don't terminate it with q)

Here is another variant that you might want to play around with. In this version an ongoing make will be killed and restarted if you change the code. However, there will be no screen paging of the output (this is difficult to combine with a background process):

```
BGPID=0
while inotifywait -qqr /dir/to/watch; do
   [ "$BGPID" -gt 1 ] && kill $BGPID
   (make | tail -f)&
   BGPID=$!
done
```

Comment: The recompilation will not be triggered until `less` terminates (by pressing `q`).

Comment: You're correct that the recompile will hang until less terminates. A slight variation is to put the less command after done. Just updated the answer with this. Still, I realize that it's not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using less try tail like below.

make command:

`make 2&>1 /output/file`

and tail command in the other terminal:

`tail -f /output/file`

That should show you a live stream of all changes occurring.

Comment: Yes, but I will not be able to see all the errors (by scrolling into the file).

Comment: If you want to search for specific things like errors you can grep on the tail -f for keywords like "ERROR".  Just change the command to be `tail -f /output/file | grep ERROR` and it will only show errors, hopefully decreasing the scrolling off screen.